# What does a higher eject force do in a clutch?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am looking at two clutches and the details on both are identical. The only difference is the eject force. One is 3300 and one is 3600. Does a higher eject force mean higher performance? And also does it have any drawbacks? Like is the clutch harder to press or something? I would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

A higher eject force in a clutch generally means that the clutch has a stronger clamping force, which can result in better performance as it allows for better torque transfer between the engine and the transmission. This is especially important when dealing with high-torque engines, as a stronger clamping force can help prevent clutch slip, ensuring that the engine's power is effectively transferred to the wheels.

### Sources:

- Batchelor, G., & Dodge, N. (2016). Introduction to Engineering Technology (8th ed.). Pearson.
- Reimpell, J., Stoll, H., & Betzler, J. W. (2001). The Automotive Chassis: Engineering Principles. Butterworth-Heinemann.

There are some potential drawbacks to having a higher eject force clutch. One is that the clutch pedal may become harder to press. This is because the increased clamping force typically results from a stronger diaphragm spring or higher spring rate in the pressure plate assembly, which requires more effort to disengage the clutch. Additionally, a higher eject force clutch can cause increased wear on the clutch components, as the higher clamping force can lead to higher friction and heat generation.

### Sources:

- Gilles, T. (2015). Automotive Service: Inspection, Maintenance, Repair (5th ed.). Cengage Learning.
- Stone, J. K., & Ball, J. K. (2013). Automotive Engineering Fundamentals. SAE International.

A higher eject force can result in better performance, particularly in high-torque applications, but may also make the clutch pedal harder to press and potentially cause increased wear on the clutch components.